# How do I put the Client ID into the URL of the OAuth Consent screen?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-signin, verification, clientid

Verification requires, "Enlarge the OAuth Consent Screen to show the URL including the Client ID."

Current URL does not include the Client ID: https://accounts.google.com/signin/oauth/consent?authuser=0&part=AJi8hAMRuFPYGcXCHIgB6N1S-ySmT4htd8x6LN_73gmoBWAbbXTG4Uu_M6iwOgEo1DIXGtHqnLBBtOR....

How do I put the Client ID into the URL of the OAuth Consent screen?

Comment: That looks like an intermediate path, what platform are you running on? On most platforms, you construct the authorization URL yourself or use a client library that does it for you. For example: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#redirecting

Comment: Your comment led to a suggestion to add the following: <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="YOUR_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com">
Where do I add this?